# xpath preceding-sibling solution

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image]

Now I need to get content of class odd or just text from `<td> 161.5 </td>`

so i wrote:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[span[@class=" odds-wrap " and @eu="1.90"]]/preceding-sibling::td')
```

and and it works.

My question is: Is it possible to get the same content using one more condition, for example `title="bet365"`.. So, I want to get the same result, but using one more condition from another sibling element..

edit

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[preceding-sibling::td/span[@class=" odds-wrap " and @eu="1.90"] and following-sibling::td/div/a[@title="bet365"]]')
for ele in element:
    print(ele.text)
```

not find and print anything, I do not know why

Comment: there is also `following-sibling` if you want to go the other direction. Or you want something like "between"?

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling`:

```
//td[following-sibling::td/span[@class=" odds-wrap " and @eu="1.90"] and preceding-sibling::td/a[@title="bet365"]]
```

Comment: Thank you,I'm trying this combination but so far no results

Comment: @JakeSully365 should work in theory, can you share a link to the target page so that I can try and reproduce this problem as well? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following xpath

```
//span[@class=" odds-wrap " and @eu="1.90"]/preceding::a[@title='bet365']/following::td[1]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14577766)

Comment: The above xpath is correct and validated ,no clarification is seeked here from asker.